# selinux http_port_t vs http_cache_port_t

Tags: selinux

I need Wildfly listens to another port.

I know I need to change selinux in order to allow it.

Nevertheless, I've found exists two possible rules to change: `http_port_t`, and `http_cache_port_t`.

Questions:

1. What do I need to modify?
2. What does each one stand for?

Comment: Update your question with the output of `semanage port -l | grep http`. And also the output of `/var/log/messages` after changing WildFly. Be sure to have `setroubleshoot-server` packages installed.

Answer (score 2):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435655/nginx-proxy-pass-not-working-in-selinux (and https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Labels#Managing_TCP_and_UDP_port_labels), I think you need to modify `http_port_t`.

http_port_t describes the ports associated with webservers, where I believe http_cache_port_t describes the ports associated with proxies (Squid, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the changes you need to do by running `sealert`. `sealert` is a parth of `setroubleshoot-server` - install it with `yum install setroubleshoot-server`.

When you have it on your server, do `sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log > log.txt` and when you view the results in `log.txt` you will see what was blocked by selinux, why it was blocked and what do you need to do to fix it.